# I used TensoFlow 2.0 and python3.6 to train MNIST dataset with 99.68% accuracy but it predict the digit wrong

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

Here I train my sequential model with one hidden layer with activation function relu and softmax.
I also cheacked the dataset image and then input the same type of image to predict with a simple model. But it fails to predict correctly. If the accuracy is high then why I get the wrong prediction can't understand.

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

    x_train = x_train / 255.0
    x_train = x_train.reshape(-1,28,28,1)

    model =tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(512,activation=tf.nn.relu),
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation=tf.nn.softmax)
            ])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x=x_train,y=y_train, epochs=40)

    def input_image(filepath):
        img_size = 28  
        # read in the image and convert to grayscale
        img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 

         # resize image to match model's expected size
        new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (img_size, img_size)) 

        # return the image with shaping that TF wants
        return new_array.reshape(-1, img_size, img_size, 1) 

    #here call the input_image function which return an nested list
    prediction = model.predict([input_image("/home/farhana/Desktop/image processing/code/2.png")]) 

    print(prediction)

   print(np.argmax(prediction))
```

Comment: Have you tried other test images? It is unlikely, but there's still a 0.32% chance that your net produces an incorrect label.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you are not normalizing the test data in your input_image function. Try to add a line where you divide the loaded image by 255.0 like you did in the case of the training set. See the code below:

```
def input_image(filepath):
    img_size = 28  
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (img_size, img_size))
    new_array = new_array / 255.0

    return new_array.reshape(-1, img_size, img_size, 1)
```

Comment: You should try with a few more examples rather than only one. If it repeats, at the beginning verify your model on the test set which you created at the very first line of your code. If it works fine there might be a problem with your data, which is hard to help you without seeing the images.